# Datatype modification of the elements in array type column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame with below schema for the column col.

```
col:array
    element:struct
      Id:string
      Seq:int
      Pct:double
      Amt:long
```

When the data is not available below is the structure that comes

```
col:array
   element:string
```

The column can contain data and can be empty.

When the data is available it is in below format from source:

```
{"Id": "123456-1", "Seq": 1, "Pct": 0.1234, "Amt": 3000}
```

When the data is not available I am putting a default as below:

```
.withColumn("col", when (size($"col") === 0, array(lit("A").cast("string"), lit(0).cast("int"), lit(0.0).cast("double"))).otherwise($"col")
```

For the empty data I am getting the data seems to be casted to string:

```
["A", "0", "0.0", "0.0"]
```

How can I get the below output:

```
{"Id": "A", "Seq": 0, "Pct": 0.0}
```

When data is available in source below is the output:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|   Data                                             |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|[[236711-1, 0.14, 1.5, 1], [236711-1, 0.14, 2.0, 2]]|
|[[1061605-1, 0.011, 1.0, 1]]                        |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

When data is not avaialble

```
| Data |
+------+
|[]    |
+------+
```

Comment: The source format does not look like an array of strings

Comment: I have updated the schema!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of one struct instead of an array:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "col",     
    df.schema("col").dataType match {
        case ArrayType(StringType, _) =>
            array(
                struct(
                    lit("A").cast("string").as("Id"), 
                    lit(0).cast("int").as("Seq"), 
                    lit(0.0).cast("double").as("Pct")
                )
            )
        case ArrayType(StructType(_), _) => $"col"
    }
)
```

Comment: thanks I have a long column too but when I add that lit(0).cast("long") it changes to big int and fails with datatype mismatch

Comment: Then it means that your column is not of long type. Would you be able to do a `df.printSchema()` and provide the results in the question?

Comment: I have updated the schema. It is coming as long! but it is getting changed to big int when I run  lit(0).cast("long")

Comment: could you show the complete error message for `datatype mismatch`?

Comment: It seems your column is of array<string> type, rather than array<struct>. You can't put a struct in a column of array<string> type.

Comment: or try removing `.otherwise($"col")`?

Comment: removing the otherwise($"col") worked. I handled the Null values in the next dataframe! So is it evaluating both when and otherwise ?

Comment: Yes, the data type of when/otherwise has to be the same.

Comment: how can we make both having same type?

Comment: Just remove otherwise

Comment: removing works when there is no data...but when there is data it shows up as Null and not the original column data!

Comment: It's very hard to guess how your data looks like. Would you mind posting a sample dataframe?

Comment: added it in the question body towards the end!

Comment: I suppose these are two separate dataframes? If so, you can just handle them separately. For the second dataframe, remove `.otherwise`.

Comment: no they are same...reading json file and sometimes there is data for the column and sometimes it wont have it...when it doesnt have it then the calculated new column premium is defaulted to 0 else if data is there then there are few calculation needs to be done to populate the column premium! no matter what I do I end up with error need struct type but got string when no data is coming from source for the column

Comment: is there any way to change the schema of the column from array(string) to struct when data is not available for the column?

Comment: I think I understand it better now... Try using pattern matching in the edited answer.